# altbeacon - constants for calculating distance

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm writing my bachelor thesis on indoor navigation using iBeacons. For this i use trilateration to find my position. I've been using the android beacon library, which is now known as the AltBeacon library to detect beacons and calculate the distance. I noticed, that the distances i get aren't that accurate and after some searching here, i came across a post from DavidYoung saying that because most device have different Bluetooth antennas i would have to take that into account when im calculating the distance.
The AltBeacon library calculates the distance like this (taken from DavidYoungs [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338031/radius-networks-ibeacon-ranging-fluctuation/21340147#21340147)):

```
protected static double calculateAccuracy(int txPower, double rssi) {
  if (rssi == 0) {
    return -1.0; // if we cannot determine accuracy, return -1.
  }

  double ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
  if (ratio < 1.0) {
    return Math.pow(ratio,10);
  }
  else {
    double accuracy =  (0.89976)*Math.pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;    
    return accuracy;
  }
}
```

My question now is:
how do i calculate these values (0.89976, 7.7095, 0.111) for my Lg G2 with RSSI measurements at certain meter intervals from the beacon?
I found [this](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calcs/nexus5.html) as an example for measurement values with the calculated coefficent.

> Nexus 5 Distance Data
>
> Meters  RSSI
>   0.25    -41
>   0.5     -43 
>   1       -49 
>   2       -65 
>   3       -58 
>   4       -57 
>   5       -67
>   6       -67 
>   7       -77 
>   8       -70 
>   9       -69 
>   10      -75 
>   12      -72 
>   14      -72 
>   16      -78 
>   18      -83 
>   20      -81 
>   25      -81 
>   30      -75 
>   40      -83
>
> Android device:
>    version: 4.4.2 
>   build_number: LPV79 
>   model: Nexus 5
>   manufacturer: LGE
>   
>   Beacon Info:
>  
>   RadBeacon Tag 
>   Advertisements per second: 10
>    Transmit Power: Max
>   
>   IPhone 5s Average RSSI @1m: -51
>
> Distance formula coefficients calculated for these values:
>   Intercept: 0.1820634    
>   Multiplier: 0.8229884  
>   Power: 6.6525179

The term intercept suggests linear regression, but when i put the values into a linear regression calculator it gave me results that were nowhere near those values.
I hope you can help me and that my question is clear enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many kinds of formulas you can use when doing a best-fit regression.  For distance calculations, we use a power curve, fitting to which is supported by the free R statistical package.  You can read more about how to do this here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/47

While getting a device-specific formula will help you get better distance estimates, much of the error you are seeing from trilateration output is probably from signal noise, attenuating obstructions and multipath.  Understand that even with a device-specific formula, beacon ranging is inexact and precision gets worse the further you are away from the device.  To mitigate these effects, space your beacons as closely as possible with clear line of sight to the mobile device if possible.

Comment: thank you, im already on the point where i have to say that this isn't terribly practical. I have multiple stages where i take the average of the values and im contemplating implementing walkpath which limit the possible positions considerably. But all this takes a lot of time, thanks to the slow advertising interval. And i've just looked over the link you posted, that solves my question, thank you :)

Comment: Regarding the slow advertising interval, one thing that does help is to increase this to at least 10Hz.  This gives you more samples in a time period to average which helps filter out noise.

Comment: I haven't found the option for that yet when configuring the beacons. I will check again, thanks :)